# SharePoint Online SDK not available as a reference

Tags: c#, sharepoint, visual-studio-2013

I have Windows 7 64-bit and Visual Studio Ultimate 2013.

I downloaded the SharePoint Online Client Components SDK (x64) from the following URL: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42038.

I am trying to follow the example on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163783(v=office.15).aspx however the Microsoft.SharePoint.Client; line is saying that it doesn't contain any public member or cannot be found.

I think I can kind of see why as I do not see Microsoft.SharePoint.Client in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT; but maybe that has nothing to do with it as I can still find some registry information about Microsoft.SharePoint.Client; however, When I go to the properties of my Project and go to the references tab I can not see the "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client" as a reference that I can check either. I am not really sure where to start. Perhaps some dlls need to be regserved or regasmed? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Sean W.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok that was silly; but, I figured it out. When I go to the Properties of my project and on to the References tab I needed to press "Add..." and then click on to the "Extensions" tab and then I could see the "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client" references there and it looks like I am able to continue coding.